# Expected Value for coin flips for five heads.

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a coin that comes up heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p$ We
flip this coin (independently) and stop as soon as it comes up heads for the 5th time. Let X be the random variable whose value is the total number of times we 
flip the coin. What is the expected value E(X) of X?

---

I'm unsure on how to find the expected value of this.

Can we use the $E(X) = np$ rule for this type of question, if so then the answer would be $5p$.

Possible answers (one of the following): $$\frac{5}{p},5p,\frac{1}{p^5}, p^5$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the negative-binomial distribution?

Comment: So I justed searched it up, what makes this NBD? Is expected value of NBD $\frac{r}{p}$ where $r=5$ and $p$ is my probability?

Comment: If $X\, is\,Negative-Binomial(5, p) \,then\, E(x)=5(1-p)/p$

Comment: @undergrad I don't think it is a negative binomial distribution. The possible answers are: $\frac{5}{p}, 5p, \frac{1}{p^5}, p^5$

Comment: Well $X > 5$, but $5p < 5$. I think what you need is $Xp=5$

Comment: The Negative Binomial(5, p) counts the number of failures (tails) until the fifth success(head). Let Y be the number of tails. E(Y) = 5(1-p)/p. E(X) = E(Y) + 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average amount of time you need to wait til the first heads is $\frac{1}{p}$ (this is the mean of a geometric distribution with parameter $p$ - the time it takes for the first head to appear when iid coins are flipped with heads probability $p$). After you get the first heads, you wait on average another $\frac{1}{p}$ for the second heads, since the geometric distribution si memoryless. So on so forth, and you get $\frac{5}{p}$. Alternatively, you can use the negative binomial distribution as suggested in the comments.